# Which way is the best to manage a workstation from windows server 2008?

Tags: networking, windows, server, administration

I mean, are there any tools to manage mixed networks with Windows and Ubuntu workstations from single Windows Server 2008? Some like GPO or Windows Managment Console.

Answer (score 3):

you can check out Landscape by Canonical (the company that backs ubuntu)

http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape

but there are only paid licencing models.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, well-known for their free [Likewise Open](http://www.likewise.com/products/likewise_open/) product which authenticates Linux against Active Directory, also has a commercial [Likewise Enterprise](http://www.likewise.com/products/likewise_enterprise/) product, which does what you describe.

Likewise Enterprise supports a bunch of policies and integrates fully with Group Policy Management Console and Group Policy Object Editor, making the Linux workstation into a full AD client. Seems like a great tool to manage Linux from Windows. It's not free though, and I've not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn Heemels mentioned in his answer, there's Likewise Enterprise, which [I've reviewed](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Linux-and-Open-Source/Likewise-Extends-Active-Directory-Embrace-to-Mac-and-Linux/), and which worked pretty much as advertised--you can control the stuff in gconf through group policy.

There's also Centrify, which I haven't tested, but which is supposed to work more or less like Likewise. I noticed that Centrify's free version, which allows for AD authentication (Likewise Open does the same) is now available in Canonical's partner repo, so that's two options for AD auth with an up-sell to GP admin, both of which explicitly support Ubuntu.

If you end up deploying one of these, I'd love to hear how you fare.